# How I can access appsetting of server project in client-side-blazored Project.cs

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly, blazor-editform, blazored

"I want to know how i can access **appsettings.json** in **client side balzored** **project**.cs file."

Comment: Is your client side a Blazor Webassembly or a BlazorServer generated page? Specifying this might help find the correct answer.

Comment: What do you mean by `Project.cs` could you please share your relevant code snippet?

Comment: Program.cs file

Comment: There is not straight way, you have create a `method` in backend which will access your `appsettings.json` and need to call that `method/api` from your client side.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.